# What happend when you write a path for linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

I made a patch in linux kernel, and received a email with applied, what is the next step? wait?

Comment: Yes. More details [here](http://connect.linaro.org/resource/bud17/bud17-tr02/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just wait :-)
You've got an answer from the maintainer of the branch where your patch has been applied. Now it should arrive soon in [linuxt-next](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git). Then, at the next merge window, your dedicated maintainer will send a pull-request to linus and your patch will land in official linux kernel tree.